# Why am I getting an object-defined error while adjust which rows I want to clear?

Tags: vba

I have a specific template that starts it's printed array data in cell B9, but I just want rows 9-rows.count to be cleared of it's contents (not deleted because I have drop-down menus in there).

```
Rows(8).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rows.Count - 1).EntireRow.ClearContents
```

doesn't seem to work, but it did work when I had `Rows(1).Offset(1,0)` etc... in there. why is it now not wanting to work when I adjusted the row number to start on?

Comment: Read the documentation for [Range.Resize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize). The parameter is the number of rows. You're attempting to resize the Range to include a bottom row that is higher than the maximum row count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rows.Count` gives the maximum numbers of rows in a worksheet (usually 1'048'576).

Splitting your command `Rows(8).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rows.Count - 1)`:

`Rows(8)` gives you the row 8 (`$8:$8`)

`.Offset(1, 0)` gives you the next row (`$9:$9`)

`.Resize(Rows.Count - 1)` asks the range that starts at row 9 to be resized so that it is 1'048'576 rows "high". However, that would mean row 9 until row **1'048'585**, and that would be behind the maximum number of rows.

What you probably meant is to delete until the end of your data. Is is not an easy task to figure out the end of the data, usually it is done with a construct like
`rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row`. This will (virtually) jump to cell B1048576, simulate the key "Ctrl+Up" and (again virtually) jumps to the last row holding data in that column. Change the `2` into any other column number (`A` would be 1...) if you want to check that column.

Try the following code:

```
Dim rowCount As Long
With ActiveSheet
    rowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    .Rows(8).Offset(1, 0).Resize(rowCount - 1).EntireRow.ClearContents
End With
```

Comment: thank you a ton, an answer with some context like this helps much more than a link to the msn site which gets very confusing sometimes. I really appreciate this and it worked!